# PHP: Add metadata array to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got the following JSON array with PHP:

```
 "data": [
    {
        "RecordID": 1,
        "OrderID": "53150-422",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
```

I do this with:

```
echo json_encode(array('data' => $users),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Now I want to add metadata to the array like this:

```
{
"meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "perpage": -1,
    "total": 350,
    "sort": "asc",
    "field": "RecordID"
},
"data": [
    {
        "RecordID": 1,
        "OrderID": "53150-422",
        ...
    },
```

How to to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write code this way

```
<?php
$meta=[ "page"=> 1,
    "pages"=> 1,
    "perpage"=> -1,
    "total"=> 350,
    "sort"=> "asc",
    "field"=> "RecordID"];
$users= [

        "RecordID"=> 1,
        "OrderID"=> "53150-422"

];

echo json_encode(array('meta'=>$meta,'data' => $users),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);    
?>
```

Comment: your welocme @cr1zz